# Check Box field is not updating to properly in opportunity through processbuilder to bypass the validation Rule During Conversion

Tags: process-builder

I have created process Builder to update the checkbox field to false after 1minute of lead conversion but it is not working properly in production and working properly in the sandbox the formula fiveminutes is (Now() - 0.0409) also tried with immediate action by adding criteria in entry condition but it is hitting validation rule of opportunity any idea of how to update the checkbox field of opportunity to false after lead conversion

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please post your validation rule and what don't you consider rule trigger date instead of the custom field(five minutes) in time trigger?

Comment: validation rule :AND( Source_Check__c =false,

ISPICKVAL( LeadSource , 'Partner')
,
ISBLANK( Partner_Account__c )
)

Comment: Could you please add this condition too in your validation rule? $Profile.Name <> 'System admin profile name'

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are trying to bypass the validation rule on the opportunity object while lead conversion. Follow the below steps to achieve the solution.

1. Create a field named Source check-in both lead(By-default field will be true) & opportunity(By-default field will be false) object.
2. Map this field from lead to opportunity(default field mapping).
3. Change the validation rule like below.

   ```
   If(ISNew(),AND(Source_Check__c =false, ISPICKVAL( LeadSource , 'Partner') , ISBLANK( 
    Partner_Account__c )),AND(ISPICKVAL( LeadSource , 'Partner') , ISBLANK( 
    Partner_Account__c )))
   ```

From my perspective, we don't require the above process builder in this use case